# Python equivalent of Unique function in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, unique

I have a (654 x 2) matrix of integers where many rows are having values which are just permutations of the same column values. (Eg. a certain row has values [2,5] whereas another row has values [5,2]). I need a Python function which treats both the rows as unique and help me deleting the row which comes later when sorted.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of how your matrix looks like!

Comment: Ye request may lead to some breakage or inconsitensies. Consider the 2 by 2 matrix represented as a list of lists `m = [[a, b], [c, d]]`. Now let it be the case that `a` is equivalent to `d` according to ye rules (e.g. `a is [5, 2]; d is [2, 5]`). Now reomve `d` as you wish, you get ` [[a, b], [c]]`. Now ye don't have a matrix any more, for what then is the order of the new structure. Moral of the story: revisit thine problem, for the current phrasing is not consitent with the definition of a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort each element in the sublist.

```
a = [[1,2], [3, 4], [2,1]]

#Sorted each element in sublist, I converted list to tuple to provide it as an input in set
li = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in a]
print(li)
#[(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 2)]
```

Then use `set` to eliminate duplicates.

```
#Convert tuple back to list
unique_li = [list(t) for t in set(li)]
print(unique_li)
#[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please consider accepting my answer since it helped you @saumavadey :) ! And upvote too if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy to sort your array's rows.

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4], [2,1]])
a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [2, 1]])

np.ndarray.sort(a)
a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2]])
```

The use aray_equal to compare for equality of rows:

```
np.array_equal(a[0], a[1])
False
np.array_equal(a[0], a[2])
True
```

And then remove rows using:

```
np.delete(a, 2, 0)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: As written, this scales up very badly